# How to store string array return from an object and display it in message box?

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, oop

I want to display data in messagebox inside an array returned from an object function, the function seems to working fine, but i dont know how to store its returned value into an array on my main class, when i tried to run the program the messagebox doesn't show up

Below is the function for getSubject:

```
 public string[] getSubject(string id, string sem, string schoolyear)
        {
            string[] subject;
            int rows = 0;
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            string count = "SELECT * FROM grades WHERE student_school_id='" + id + "' AND semester='" + sem + "' AND school_year='" + schoolyear + "'";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(count, connection);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                rows++;
            }
            subject = new string[rows];
            string query = "SELECT subject FROM grades WHERE student_school_id ='" + id + "' AND semester='" + sem + "' AND school_year='" + schoolyear + "'";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < subject.Length; i++)
                    {
                        subject[i] = reader["subject"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            return subject;
        }
```

now i want to display it in Messagebox, the code:

```
string[] subject = { db.getSubject("2015-0895-A", "1", "2019-2020").ToString() };
                string display = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, subject);
                MessageBox.Show(display);
```

i don't know how to proceed on this point, array size has been set in the getSubject function which will depend on number of rows in the query result, can someone help? Will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: sorry bout that i'm still new to mysql c# so i didn't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> getSubject(string id, string sem, string schoolyear)
{
    string query = "SELECT distinct subject FROM grades WHERE student_school_id = @id AND semester= @semester AND school_year= @year";

    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    {
        //use actual types and lengths for the database columns
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.TinyText, 11).Value = id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@semester", MySqlDbType.TinyText, 1).Value = semester;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", MySqlDbType.TinyText, 9).Value = schoolyear;

        connection.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string result = (string)reader["subject"];
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var subject = db.getSubject("2015-0895-A", "1", "2019-2020");
string display = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, subject);
MessageBox.Show(display);
```

The query parameter placeholders, when used this way, protect you from sql injection, and the `using` block will ensure the connection is closed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: so the number beside MysqlDbType.TinyText is the actual parameter length passed to the object? thank you very much, learned a lot from this

Comment: That is correct. I don't know your database, so I have to guess, but you should check the columns and put those actual lengths in, instead.... though I just realized you had sample data, so I've updated to infer some lengths from that. You should also change the MySqlDbType as appropriate

Comment: oh i see, so MysqlDbType should change depending on data type of column inside table? thanks i'll go search for representation for each datatype on MysqlDbType, this has been a big help to me GOD bless you sir

Answer (score 1):

`getSubject()` already returns a `string[]`, so just do this:

```
string[] subject = db.getSubject(....);
string display = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, subject);
MessageBox.Show(display);
```